# Django, gunicorn, and nginx proxy: static files give 404

Tags: django, nginx, centos7, gunicorn

I am running a development of a django project via gunicorn on my local machine. For reasons™, I want to set up nginx as a proxy for it. So far so, good:

```
location /intranet {
    return 301 /intranet/;
}

location /intranet/ {
    rewrite ^/intranet(.*) /$1 break; 
    proxy_redirect default;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

This does the trick nicely. However, none of the static files are severed: all I get is 404 for those.

*How can I modify the above nginx configuration so that the static content is severed?*

Note that using `https::127.0.0.1:8000`, the static files are served just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project you shoud point the URL:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

If you have a static folder in every app you can use:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

This grabs all your static files and put them on the same static folder (STATIC_ROOT)

Then your Ngnix also must to know where statifiles are stored

```
server {
    access_log /pathto/log/acces.log;
    error_log  /pathto/log/error.log;
    server_name ******
    charset     utf-8;

    location /static {
        alias /path/to/your/static; <---- This Line
    }

    location /intranet/ {
        rewrite ^/intranet(.*) /$1 break; 
        proxy_redirect default;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a `403 Forbidden`… Despite the directory being owned by (group) nginx and having set selinux's `httpd_sys_content_t:s0` permissions. Ideas?

Comment: Depends on your willing to have a secure static folder. First of all set all permisions to check if this works: "chmod 777 static" if this works, you can fight with grups and permissions. :P

Comment: `chmod 777` is a bad idea™ and in any case does not help whatsoever.

Comment: y normally use 755, but for debug if is it working, is not a bad idea. Make sure is working, if is working the question of permisions it belongs to serverfault